# Looping through an object and changing one value

Tags: javascript, loops, object

I need a loop that will go around the entire object and reduce the price of all products by 20%.

```
const products = {
product1: {
    name: 'Pasta',
    price: 25,
    quanity: 5,
},
product2: {
    name: 'Pizza',
    price: 20,
    quanity: 3,
},
product3: {
    name: 'Cola',
    price: 8,
    quanity: 4,
},
```

};

Im new and still learning but i really dont know how to start it.

Comment: *"i really dont know how to start"*: start by solving the problem for one object (not an array of them). If that is too hard, then start by solving the problem for a given price (an integer, not an object). Then extend from there to an object, and finally to an array of objects. If you cannot make it work, show your work where you attempt to follow this guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a basic way to code it. You just need to use the const variable your making of products and multiple the product# price by .8 that will reduce the total. Get used to adding comments to your code also it helps a lot for debugging and for making the logic clear.

```
    // Define an object named 'products' to store information about three products
const products = {
  // Product 1
  product1: {
    name: 'Pasta', // Product name
    price: 25, // Product price in USD
    quantity: 5, // Product quantity in stock
  },

  // Product 2
  product2: {
    name: 'Pizza', // Product name
    price: 20, // Product price in USD
    quantity: 3, // Product quantity in stock
  },

  // Product 3
  product3: {
    name: 'Cola', // Product name
    price: 8, // Product price in USD
    quantity: 4, // Product quantity in stock
  },
};

// Iterate through the 'products' object and reduce the price of each product by 20%
for (const productId in products) {
  // Get the current product object using the product ID
  const product = products[productId];

  // Reduce the price of the product by 20% using the *= operator
  product.price *= 0.8;
}

// Print the updated 'products' object to the console
console.log(products);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, now i understand it. Next task was to add to new array products that quanity is below 5. Based on your solution, I managed to do it by myself. Thank you very much!

Comment: seems AI generated

Comment: I'm an novice not an AI @AlexanderNenashev I literally only took coding for one semester in college and haven't used it properly ever since.

Comment: @potion If the answer solved your problem, consider accepting it by clicking the checkbox on the left of this answer.